# Prove that an identity element does not exist with the definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the operation $a \circ b=(a^2+1) \log(|b|+1)$.

How can I prove that this particular operation does not have an identity element?

Comment: Note that for all $a,b$, $a\circ b\geq0$, and if $b\neq0$, then $a\circ b>0$. So what happens when $a=-1$?

Comment: @DonThousand, no obligation to have $0$ be the identity element for this operation?

Comment: What @DonThousand means is that if the operation always results in $>0$ then it cannot be an identify since applying it to a negative number cannot return that number.

Comment: In general to find an identity simply solve for $a\circ x=x\circ a = a\implies x=???$ If a constant solution always exists then $x$ is the identity. If the solution doesn't always exist or is dependent upon $a$ there is no identity. Don Thousand's excellent comment is that solutions don't exist if $a$ is negative.  Aqua's excellent answer is more general in that any solution is dependent upon $a$ and not a constant identity.

Answer (score 1):

Say there exists such $e$. So for all $a$ we would have $$a\circ e = a$$ i.e. $$ \log(|e|+1) = {a\over a^2+1}$$

Since the left side of the equation is constant and right is not, there is no such element (right identity) $e$.

Say exists left identity element $e$, then we have for all $b$: $$e^2+1 = {b\over \log (|b|+1)}$$ which is clearly nonconstant again.